# leaflet change attribution prefix on baselayer change

Tags: leaflet, basemap, attribution

In leaflet is there a way to change the attribution prefix when a specific baselayer change happens using the default layer control?

Answer (score 1):

This is what I did, but I was hoping there was an option to set the layer's prefix on creation:

```
var baseLayers = {
  "Streets": streets,
  "Satellite": imagery,
  "Topographic": topo
};


map.on('baselayerchange', function (e) {
  if(e.name == 'Streets'){
    map.attributionControl.setPrefix('<a href="http://leafletjs.com" title="A JS library for interactive maps">Leaflet</a>');
  }else{
    map.attributionControl.setPrefix('<a href="http://leafletjs.com" title="A JS library for interactive maps">Leaflet</a> | Powered by <a href="https://www.esri.com">Esri</a>');
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

For reference, the Leaflet [Attribution Control](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.3.0.html#control-attribution) concatenates its [prefix](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.3.0.html#control-attribution-prefix) and [attributions](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.3.0.html#layer-attribution) from the layers currently added on map:

> it fetches attribution texts from layers […] automatically.

Therefore, should you include your specific string in your layers' attribution, you could achieve an effect similar to what you have done using `map.attributionControl.setPrefix`:

```
var streets = L.tileLayer(urlTemplateStreets, {
  attribution: 'Some info'
});

var imagery = L.tileLayer(urlTemplateImagery, {
  attribution: 'Powered by (provider) | other info'
});
```

- When only the `streets` layer is on map, the default attribution would display "Leaflet | Some info"
- When it is replaced by `imagery` layer, the display would automatically change to "Leaflet | Powered by (provider) | other info"

Live example: https://plnkr.co/edit/81kncgMwXRJU7xR5jZAy?p=preview

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. I am using attributions when creating the layers. However, a plugin is setting the prefix when activated. I wanted to remove its prefix when layers that do not use the plugin are active.